# How to use "runOnUiThread(runnable)" inside static method?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, static

I'm writing code in two different classes. The first one runs IOIO Thread which reads pins status of an IOIO board; when this thread is running, it will update the several TextViews which are on the other class (Tab3Activity.java).

I called the method to update the UI just like the code below.

```
Tab3Activity.setText(index,"string here");
```

the `setText()` above need to be static otherwise it gives an err

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setText(int, String) from the     type Tab3Activity

The problem is on the Tab3Activity.java.

```
public static void setText(final int idx,final String str) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            _textview[idx].setText(str);
        }
    });
}
```

the `runOnUiThread` above gives an err.

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method runOnUiThread(Runnable) from the type Activity

This is the IOIO Thread code written in Globalioio.java, i'm trying to update the UI on the Tab3Activity.java. Look at the `Loop()` method.

```
class Looper extends BaseIOIOLooper {

    @Override
    public void setup() throws ConnectionLostException {
        //setup DigitalOutputs, AnalogInputs etc here.
        if(Tab2Activity.isOpened==true){
            led_ = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(0, true);

            pwm1S = ioio_.openPwmOutput(10, 100);
            pwm1S.setDutyCycle((float)Tab2Activity.pwm1Speed.getProgress()/100);
            pwm1Move = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(11, false);

            pwm2S = ioio_.openPwmOutput(12, 100);
            pwm2S.setDutyCycle((float)Tab2Activity.pwm2Speed.getProgress()/100);
            pwm2Move = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(13, false);

            pwmSrvo1 = ioio_.openPwmOutput(26, 100);
            pwmSrvo1.setDutyCycle((float)Tab2Activity.servo1.getProgress()/100);
            pwmSrvo2 = ioio_.openPwmOutput(27, 100);
            pwmSrvo2.setDutyCycle((float)Tab2Activity.servo2.getProgress()/100);
        }
        if(Tab3Activity.isOpened==true){
            sensor1 = ioio_.openAnalogInput(41);
            sensor2 = ioio_.openAnalogInput(42);
            for(int i = 0;i<30;i++){
                    dInput[i] = ioio_.openDigitalInput(DIGITAL_SENSOR_PIN[i]);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
                aInput[i] = ioio_.openAnalogInput(ANALOG_SENSOR_PIN[i]);
            }
        }

        connStatus=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException {
        try {
            if(Tab3Activity.slideDrawer2.isOpened()==true){
                final float range1 = (float)(2914/(sensor1.read() * 675.18+5))-1;
                Tab3Activity.setSeekBarSensor(0,(int) (range1));
                Tab3Activity.setTextSensor(0,Float.toString((range1)));
                final float range2 = (float)(2914/(sensor2.read() * 675.18+5))-1;
                Tab3Activity.setSeekBarSensor(1,(int) (range2));
                Tab3Activity.setTextSensor(1,Float.toString(range2));

            }
            if(Tab3Activity.slideDrawer1.isOpened()==true){
                if(Tab3Activity.pinsGroup==0){
                    int idx =0;
                    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
                       final boolean readingD = dInput[i].read();
                       if(readingD==true){
                           Tab3Activity.setSeekBar(idx,(int) (100));
                       }else{
                           Tab3Activity.setSeekBar(idx,(int) (0));
                       }
                       Tab3Activity.setText(idx,Boolean.toString(readingD));
                       idx++;
                    }
                }else if(Tab3Activity.pinsGroup==1){
                    int idx =0;
                    for(int i = 10;i<20;i++){
                          final boolean readingD = dInput[i].read();
                            if(readingD==true){
                                Tab3Activity.setSeekBar(idx,(int) (100));
                            }else{
                                Tab3Activity.setSeekBar(idx,(int) (0));
                           }
                            Tab3Activity.setText(idx,Boolean.toString(readingD));
                            idx++;
                        }
                }else if(Tab3Activity.pinsGroup==2){
                    int idx=0;
                    for(int i = 20;i<30;i++){
                          final boolean readingD = dInput[i].read();
                            if(readingD==true){
                                Tab3Activity.setSeekBar(idx,(int) (100));
                            }else{
                                Tab3Activity.setSeekBar(idx,(int) (0));
                           }
                            Tab3Activity.setText(idx,Boolean.toString(readingD));
                            idx++;
                    }
                }else if(Tab3Activity.pinsGroup==3){
                    int idx=0;
                    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
                        final float readingA = aInput[i].read();
                        Tab3Activity.setSeekBar(idx,(int) (readingA * 100));
                        Tab3Activity.setText(idx,Float.toString((readingA * 100)));
                        idx++;
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            ioio_.disconnect();
        } catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}




@Override
public IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper(String arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Looper();
}
```

Is there any alternative to do this?
please give the simple one, i'm quite new to android. Thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get when it is not static? (Maybe that's the real problem here.)

Comment: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setText(int, String) from the type Tab3Activity"
it suggests me to change the method to the static one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If this thread is started from the same activity

then you can pass the reference of the activity to the thread, and remove static from that method.

```
YourThread thread = new YourThread(yourActivity);
thread.start();

//YourThread
public class YourThread extends Thread
{
    Tab3Activity activity;
    public YourThread(Tab3Activity activity)
    {
       Tab3Activity.activity = activity;
    }

...
    activity.setText(index,"string here");
...
}
```

**Note:** Make sure your activity has android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize". Otherwise as you rotate your devices there will be a new instance of acitivity started.

> And if your activity is not starting that thread

then you should not try to access the activity directly through a static method.

If you are sure about your implementation and if it does not lead to a memory leak or crash then try this

Create a static MainLooper Handler in your activity or anywhere.

```
public static Handler UIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

now you can use this handler to run on ui thread.

```
public static void setText(final int idx,final String str) {
    UIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            _textview[idx].setText(str);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is,

you are coupling between your `Thread` and the `Activity` which is not a good design ,

instead use `Intent` when the Thread finish the I/O  fire  Intent and catch this inside the activity